# How to find the element on <td> markup-JSOUP

Tags: android, jsoup

I have a webpage that has a table containing different values, i want to retrieve the  values of a defined . Example

```
<td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:12pt;width:17%;">10:00 PM </td>
<td class="paddingTop paddingBottom" align="center" style="width:20%;">
    <img id="MainContent_ChannelDisplay2_GrdChannelProgs_imgProgThumbnail_26" src="../ProgramsImages/Movies/Bad%20Boys%20II.jpg" align="middle" style="border-color:White;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;width:95px;" />
</td>
<td class="Vdotline paddingTop" style="width:2%;">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="BottomGreyBorder InTxt2 paddingTop" align="left" valign="top" style="width:64%;">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b><a id="MainContent_ChannelDisplay2_GrdChannelProgs_progLink_26" class="ShowingNowTitle" href="ProgramDetails.aspx?ProgramID=2320">Bad Boys II</a></b><br />
                    <div id="2320" class="statVal">
                        <span class="ui-rater">
                            <span class="ui-rater-starsOff" style="width: 90px;">
                                <span class="ui-rater-starsOn" style="width: 63px"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="ui-rater-rating">3.5</span>
                                &#160;(<span class="ui-rater-rateCount">2</span>) 
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

I want to retrieve 10:00 PM. All other  has the same structure but with different values like 8:00 PM, 6:00PM ...
Any idea please of how making that on JSOUP.

Comment: Have you considered indenting the HTML so it's readable here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only uniqueness of your desired `td` is that is the first one you can use :

```
Elements tds = document.getElementsByTag("td"); //then access the one at 0 index
```

or try

```
Elements tds = doc.select("td"); //then access the one at 0 index
```

take a look at the docs for more options...

[Use selector-syntax to find elements](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

[Use DOM methods to navigate a document](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)

**Edit**

If you want to locate `td` of some `a` then you could do something like this:

```
Elements a= document.getElementsByTag("a");
```

then iterate over the `a` and take a peek at its `child` (`td`) some other method, look here [Element Object child method](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#child%28int%29)

or if I got you wrong

```
Elements td= document.getElementsByTag("td");
```

then iterate over the `td` and take a peek at its `child` (`a`)

Comment: No i have many <td> but i want to retrieve a td with a specific <a> inside of it. e.g the movie Y(<a>) is diffused at 10PM(<td>) wheras the movie Z is diffused at 12PM

Comment: so how do you distinguish between the various `td's` ? by movie name ?    the screening hour?

Comment: By the value passed on <a> tags(the movie name). Is that possible to select <td> tag value of a specified <a> tag value?

Comment: child method just accepts index as parameter, not a String, so i think that i can't pass that parameter for example `a#MainContent_ChannelDisplay2_GrdChannelProgs_progLink_26` on child method...

Comment: I said that you can iterate over the `Elements` with a simple for loop and access each iterated `Element` with `.child(0).text()` for example... place a break point in your code and do a little research...

Comment: I made that with no success: `Elements content = document.getElementsByTag("td");
//         
//         for (Element link : content) {
//            
//          //Elements e=link.getElementsContainingText("a#MainContent_ChannelDisplay2_GrdChannelProgs_progLink_26");
//          if(content.size() > 0) {
//
//          result=link.child(0).text("a#MainContent_ChannelDisplay2_GrdChannelProgs_progLink_26").text();
//          }
//         }`

Comment: I'd try in turn iterating over the `Elements e` and printing its `.text()` maybe you'll get some direction in that way...